# Which machine learning model can I use with the dataset visualized in figure?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, dataset, model

I have a dataset with two groups of observations, I got the plot of the two groups. Which machine learning model can I use to assess the claim that the group of observations [539:1110] assumes bigger values than the group [1:538] for the variable Dataset$views

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need a machine learning algorithm. If you simply have two groups and one variable, a T-test could assess if there is a difference between the distributions of the data. It depends what you mean by "bigger."

Comment: Machine learning is not needed here; this is a job for statistical hypothesis testing. Furthermore, if you formed your hypothesis *by looking at the data*, then you would need to account for this when testing it. In particular, you would need to test using another, independent dataset that you haven't  looked at yet.